# JQuery datatable with ajax, post API call hook

Tags: ajax, datatables, pagination

I am implementing jquery DataTable with server-side pagination. Refer code snippet below -

**Script**

```js
$(async function() {
    $('#registry_table').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'localhost:3000/provenance/registries',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
            data: () => {
               return {page: 0, per_page: 5};
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'name', defaultContent: 'N/A'},
            {data: 'created', defaultContent: 'N/A'},
            {data: 'extrinsic', defaultContent: 'N/A'},
            {data: 'registry', defaultContent: ' <span class="text-primary bg-white fa-border d-inline-block" style="cursor: pointer" title="Rename Registry"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"/> Rename</span>'}
        ],
        language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
            search: "",
            lengthMenu: "_MENU_ &nbsp;items/page"
        }
    });
});
```

**Html**

```html
<table class="table table-striped mg-b-0" id="registry_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">#</th>
            <th class="text-left">Name</th>
            <th class="text-left">Created on</th>
            <th class="text-left">Transaction</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**API response**

```json
{
  "registries": [
    {
      "registry": 489607958,
      "created_by": "5DqdTHZLA8X2Lk2FqCPFM9kxd8GmdMbyboFiFg6gmB8sHCg4",
      "name": "test 7",
      "created": "2020-09-14T15:08:49.006766"
    },
    {
      "registry": 1421927575,
      "created_by": "5DqdTHZLA8X2Lk2FqCPFM9kxd8GmdMbyboFiFg6gmB8sHCg4",
      "name": "test 6",
      "created": "2020-09-14T15:08:43.104835"
    },
    {
      "registry": 1560576458,
      "created_by": "5DqdTHZLA8X2Lk2FqCPFM9kxd8GmdMbyboFiFg6gmB8sHCg4",
      "name": "test 4",
      "created": "2020-09-14T15:08:34.132407"
    },
    {
      "registry": 1766285412,
      "created_by": "5DqdTHZLA8X2Lk2FqCPFM9kxd8GmdMbyboFiFg6gmB8sHCg4",
      "name": "test 5",
      "created": "2020-09-14T15:08:27.376323"
    },
    {
      "registry": 155398053,
      "created_by": "5DqdTHZLA8X2Lk2FqCPFM9kxd8GmdMbyboFiFg6gmB8sHCg4",
      "name": "test 3",
      "created": "2020-09-14T15:08:16.768747"
    }
  ],
  "total": 7
}
```

If the total number of rows is **7** and `per_page` = **5**, then it should show **2** pages. But in the browser, it shows 5 pages. Also, page info shows wrong information.

**Browser**

[image]

#### My questions are-

1. Is there a way to set the number of pages/total items once data fetched
2. Page info should be `Showing 1 to 5 of 7 entries (filtered from 7 total entries)`, how to set those properly?
3. How to pass the entire row as a parameter to a function (rename button)

Note: API is in production and unlikely to change.

#### Update 1:

Script (modified **data** and added **dataSrc** with ajax section

```js
data: (d) => {
    d.page =self.page;
    d.per_page =self.per_page;
    delete d.columns;
    delete d.order;
    delete d.search;
    delete d.start;
    delete d.length;
},
dataSrc: (response) => {
    response.draw = 1;
    response.recordsTotal = response.total;
    response.recordsFiltered = response.registries.length;
    response.data = response.registries;

    return response.data;
}
```

Now it doesn't show any data but, everything else is fine.
[image]

Comment: I understand that the _API is in production and unlikely to change_, but... DataTables expects you to populate the `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` values in the JSON sent from the server to DataTables. Those fields are described [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data). An example of the JSON for that is [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data). (The request from DataTables to the server already included info on page number and items per page, using `start` and `length` - see [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters)).

Comment: I don't know any other way to provide the correct data from the server to DataTables. If you don't pass those values, you don't know what numbers to use. You can, of course, use JS or jQuery to replace your `0` and `NaN` values inside an [`initComplete()`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) function. You can use whatever numbers you want in that case - but they may not reflect the actual size of the overall data set.

Comment: @andrewjames As per your feedback, I applied some changes. Check updates in the question. Now table information is showing perfectly, but rows are not showing.

Comment: @andrewjames modified the update, now rows are showing, but number pages is 1. It should have been `2`

Comment: Looking at your screenshot: Because you have filtered the data, there are now only 5 rows displayed. Therefore there is only 1 page of results. That looks correct to me. If you remove the filter, you should see 2 pages (assuming your server-side code is handling the `search[value]` in [request parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) correctly).

Comment: Ah  I seed, changing `response.recordsFiltered = response.registries.length;` to `response.recordsFiltered = response.total;` will fix it. My API always sends the total number of rows after search  is applied. Since I can not change the API, that's the way to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221475/discussion-between-bopsi-and-andrewjames).